# Google vision api to detect a particular font

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision, vision

I am trying to collect the SYS and DIA values from bp monitors ( Ex. [omron bp monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDrhH.jpg) ) using Google Vision API, but i am not able to get the calculator font digits in the response ( I just get the other texts ).
Is there a way to detect particular fonts using GCP Vision API?

Answer (score 0):

Google’s Vision API doesn’t currently recognize seven segment fonts as used on the bp monitor. You can use the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) to have a visual representation of what the Vision API is detecting. In addition, I would recommend you check out the following [article](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/), it offers a solution for seven segment optical character recognition (SSOCR).

In the meantime, I will file a feature request to have SSOCR added to the Vision API. You can follow the updates related to that feature by clicking the “star” on the top of the following [page](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111128503).